# Why CFT operators are eigenvalues of Dilatations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition

Why all operators which we consider in CFT have **fixed Dilatation value**?

As I know in general QFT we haven't such requirement.

What if one will consider questions about operators, which are **not Dilatation eingenvalues**?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the dilation operator is not necessarily diagonalizable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_conformal_field_theory .

Comment: Is it possible to consider in theory where dilation operator is diagonalizable operators, which are not eingenvalues?

Comment: If it is diagonalizable, there is a basis of operators that are eigenvectors.

Comment: is it know, in which theories Dilation operator are diagonalizable? Is it true in $Ising_3$ CFT?

Comment: No, it is not known, and the question is not necessarily very well-defined. For example, in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_critical_Ising_model , the minimal model is not logarithmic, but other observables could be logarithmic. Percolation is thought to be logarithmic. For the 2d O(n) and Potts model, the question is in the process of being settled, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07708 .

Comment: I guess a completely rigorous proof without any unjustified assumptions is still elusive, but for a unitary CFT like Ising 2d or 3d with discrete spectrum, the expectation is that the dilation operator is diagonalizable. For a reasonably convincing argument, see Section 7.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982

Comment: Right, but this statement looks quite trivial. In a unitary CFT the dilation operator is self-adjoint, and the spectral theorem says that self-adjoint operators are diagonalizable. (The spectrum needs not be discrete.)

Answer (score 0):

Also in the article [On Scale and Conformal Invariance in Four Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2921) there's appendix about such phenomena.